# QGIS: spatialite error: no such function: st_functionname() in specific qgis project

Tags: qgis-3, spatialite

From one day to another I can't import any queryresults that contain a spatialite function as layer from DB manager anymore despite the query concluding successfully in DB manager.

```
select * from table
```

works, can be loaded as layer.

```
select *, st_area(geom) as area from table
```

works, when to be loaded it throws:

```
OGR[3] error 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select *,st_area(geom) from clusteroverlapp               no such function: st_area
Data source is invalid (In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select *,st_area(geom) from clusteroverlapp               no such function: st_area)
```

Interestingly the issue only occurs in a specific qgis project (containing a lot of layers). What could be a reason for this strange behaviour?

QGIS 3.14.16-Pi on Win 10 1607, SpatiaLite 4.3.0